# Make a Chrome PWA handle a shared URL

Tags: web, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I am making my PWA installed as an App on Android using Google Chrome handle URLs shared to it.

I have a /submit.php on my webapp server side which uses GET method

In my PWA manifest I use the following:

```
  "share_target": {
  "action": "/submit.php",
  "method": "GET",
  "enctype": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "params": {
    "url": "url"
     }
   }
```

But when a url is shared from browser or another app to my pwa (which does show up on Android share panel), the pwa is opened with submit.php and not submit.php?url=url

How do I make this happen?